# About the definition of l-adic Tate-twist

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, etale-cohomology, galois-cohomology

In the J. Tate's paper "Relations Between $K_2$ and Galois Cohomology" Let F any field $F^{\text{sep}}$ the separable closure of F $G_F=\text{Gal}(F^{\text{sep}}/F$) he defines the ($\mathbb{Z}_l,G_F$)-modules $\mathbb{Z}_l(n)$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ ($\mathbb{Z}_l$ is the ring of $l$-adic integers where $l$ is a prime different from characteristic of F) inductively as follows:

$\mathbb{Z}_l(0)=\mathbb{Z}_l$, $\mathbb{Z}_l(1)=\varprojlim{(\mu_{l^i})}$, $\mathbb{Z}_l(n+1)=\mathbb{Z}_l(n)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_l}\mathbb{Z}_l(1)$ for $n\geq 0$ and $\mathbb{Z}_l(n-1)=\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_l(1),\mathbb{Z}_l(n))$ for $n\leq 0$.

I'm not sure how $G_F$ acts in each case.

Where i can find bibliography for these definitions?.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action is trivial on $\Bbb Z_\ell(0)$.
There is a Galois action on the $\mu_{\ell^n}$: each $\sigma$
in the Galois group maps each element of $\mu_{\ell^n}$ to some
element of $\mu_{\ell^n}$. This induces the action on $\Bbb Z_\ell(1)$
(so it's basically via the Galois group of the part of the cyclotomic
extension generated by $\ell$-power roots of unity).

For general $\Bbb Z_l(n)$ the action comes from the usual way of
defining tensor products of $\Bbb G$-modules as $\Bbb G$-modules, etc.

Comment: For the positive case $n\gt 0$ $G_F$ acts diagonally?, great, i supposed the same, my doubts are in the zero case and negative case. I can suppose in the negative case that $G_F$ acts directly over the morphisms (i.e $(\sigma\cdot f)(x)=\sigma\cdot f(x)$. In "http://www.martinorr.name/blog/2015/06/26/absolute-hodge-classes-in-l-adic-cohomology/" these modules are called Tate-twists. Thanks.

Comment: I found bibliography where the action is defined diagonally in "Algebraic K-Theory II" of Hyman Bass. p. 522 "Research Problems: Arithmetic Questions in K-Theory" of J. Coates. But i can't found the negative and zero case.